# Returning a json Response from a laravel project "Cannot read Property of Null"

Tags: json, laravel-5, response, appcelerator-titanium

I have here in my php file (laravel ) after i send an email and get a response to the mobile application

```
 $msg ="email sent " ;  $erreur=false ;    
    return response()->json(['Message' => $msg, 'erreur' => $erreur]);
```

But, When I get a response using this code in my javascript file

```
sendButton.onload = function(e)
{
    Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

    var json = this.responseText;
    var response = JSON.parse(json);
    if (response.erreur == false)
    {
        alert("a Password has been send to you email ");
    }
    else
    {
        alert(response.Message);
    }
};
```

I get this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight forward the response is null

```
sendButton.onload = function(e)
{
  Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

  var json = this.responseText;
  var response = JSON.parse(json);
  if (response !=null && response.erreur == false)
  {
    alert("A password has been sent to your email.");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(response); //probably doesnt have Message either
  }
};
```

Comment: yes i know that its null but , in my PHP i set it like this
$msg ="email sent " ;  $erreur=false ;    
    return response()->json(['Message' => $msg, 'erreur' => $erreur]);

and still turns out null

Comment: So your js code needs to be stronger so it doesnt throw fatal error. That is the answer to the problem you posted. If you have problem with your api that is different issue. You don't show where you talk to the API so can't really help further

Answer (score 0):

@MikeMiller
here is my Js code that communicates with my API

```
loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if ( email.value!='')
    {
        try {
        loginReq.open("POST","http://192.168.0.105/appcelerator/public/");//my local ip im testing on my computer 

        var params = {

            email:email.value,

        };
        loginReq.send(params);


       }catch (e)
       {
        alert(e.message);
       }

    }
    else
    {
        alert("All fields are required");
    }
});
```

now here is my code in my API (php laravel )

```
 public function getPassword(Request $request)
        {
            $email = $request["email"];
            $user = \DB::table('users')
                ->where('email', $request['email'])
                ->first();
             $email = $user->email;
            session()->put('email',$email);

            if (!$user)
           {

               $msg = 'invalid email adresses';
               $erreur = true ;
           }else
                    {


                Mail::send('emails.test',['password' => $this->generatePass() ],function($message )
                {
                    $message->to(session()->get('email'),'Bonjour')->subject('welcome:');
                });
             $msg = 'Password has benn send to your email ';
             $erreur = false;
                    }
            return response()->json(['Message' => $msg, 'erreur' => $erreur]);


        }
```

when it's executed i get the email in my email adresse but the response as you know is null. that's my problem